# Error running classes

Tags: c++

Hello Im taking some C++ studies right now and Im seem to be stuck in Classes. I have made this program where I need to get the price of a slice of pizza. Simply I dont want to input data yet, just with static data in that is already in place.

Code is this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Circle
{

public:

    Circle()
    {
        radius = 0;
        area = 0;


    }


    inline void setRadius(double r)
    {
         radius = r;
    }

    inline double getArea(double radius)
    {
        return 3.14 * pow(radius, 2);
    }

private:

    double radius;
    double area;`
};


class Pizza
{

private:


    double price;
    double size;
    double costperinch;
    Circle Object;


public:

    Pizza()
    {

        price = 0;
        size = 0;
        costperinch = 0;

    }

    ~Pizza();

    inline void setPrice(double p) 
    {
        price = p;
    }

    inline void setSize(double radius) 
    {
        size = Object.getArea(radius);

    }

    inline double costPeSqIn(double size, double price)
    {
        double costperinch = size * price;
    }

};


int main()
{

    Pizza myPizza;


    myPizza.setPrice(5.0);
    myPizza.setSize(3.14);

    cout << "The cost per square inch of the pizza is ";
    cout << myPizza.costPeSqIn(myPizza.setSize, myPizza.setPrice);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

> Error 1   error C3867: 'Pizza::setSize': function call missing argument
>   list; use '&Pizza::setSize' to create a pointer to
>   member    c:\users\jorge\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\object
>   composition\object composition\main 7.21.cpp  91  1   Object Composition
>
> Error 2   error C3867: 'Pizza::setPrice': function call missing argument
>   list; use '&Pizza::setPrice' to create a pointer to
>   member    c:\users\jorge\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\object
>   composition\object composition\main 7.21.cpp  91  1   Object Composition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the line

```
cout << myPizza.costPeSqIn(myPizza.setSize, myPizza.setPrice);
```

at the end of your code. Your compiler complains because `setSize` and `setPrice` are functions but you didn't provide them with arguments. I doubt that you wanted to do this in the first place any-ways.

I actually think you wanted to have:

```
inline double costPeSqIn()
{
    return size * price;
}
```

as implementation of your `costPeSqIn` function and the line above with the error should be

```
cout << myPizza.costPeSqIn();
```

it makes way more sense that way to me.

---

The way you currently pass the setter functions into `costPeSqIn` doesn't make sense, also your original `costPeSqIn` declared a double return type but didn't return anything.

---

As for the problem with the destructor, you got:

```
~Pizza();
```

and therefore got your destructor declared. Once you declare a destructor yourself the compiler won't auto generate one for you, but since you don't have a definition anywhere either your code is ill formed.

To fix this you either gotta provide a definition of it, e.g.:

```
~Pizza()
{
    // whatever code you want
}
```

or delete the declaration so that the compiler will auto-generate a default constructor for you.

Comment: I did what you said and got error with unresolved external symbol that was referring to my destructor. I had to delete it to make it work, do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: @user3709339 updated at the end with information about your destructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand, I'm trying to get good coding habit by typing everything in!